# raster package plots are empty narrowed it to user profile but can't solve

Tags: r, raster

I have previously successfully plotted rasters in R but in the last week something has changed and I now get empty plots. I have found previous posts on this but can't find solutions that work for me.

Example suggested by someone previously on stackoverflow:

```
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
plot(r, main='Raster with 100 cells')
```

I only get an empty frame, empty legend and title - no content.
Same result using other devices (eg png)

I have pasted below session info and plotting methods. 
Windows XP.

If I log out of my user profile and log back on with an old user profile of mine, then use identical R version, packages, workspace and code I successfully plot.

Can anyone suggest where to look?

many thanks 
Jane

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>   Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252 
>   LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
>   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] raster_2.1-37 sp_1.0-9
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] grid_3.0.1      lattice_0.20-15 tools_3.0.1

```
showMethods("plot")
```

> Function: plot (package graphics)
>   x="ANY", y="ANY"
>   x="Extent", y="missing"
>   x="Raster", y="ANY"
>   x="Raster", y="Raster"
>   x="RasterLayer", y="missing"
>       (inherited from: x="Raster", y="ANY")
>   x="Spatial", y="missing"
>   x="SpatialGrid", y="missing"
>   x="SpatialLines", y="missing"
>   x="SpatialPoints", y="missing"
>   x="SpatialPolygons", y="missing"

Comment: Does it work with plot(r, useRaster = FALSE) ?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it does - in fact just logged on to say that - thanks to Robert Hijmans and John Baumgartner, I also have these insights: # this fails:
    image(volcano, useRaster=TRUE)
# While this works:
    image(volcano, useRaster=FALSE)
# as do these:
    r = raster(volcano)
    spplot(r)

    library(rasterVis)
    levelplot(r)

Comment: Perhaps it is also helpful to report the result of  Sys.info()[c('release', 'version')]  (i.e. more detailed info on the operating system)

Comment: Sure: "XP" "build 2600, Service Pack 3". Though the plotting works on this laptop (using same R installation etc) on my old user profile, but not on my new user profile.

Comment: Are you using R through RStudio or some other interface (e.g. Eclipse)?

Comment: I usually use it through RStudio but have tested it: same result through the gui/console